# Is there a limit in bits for the data hashed in hash-locked script?

Tags: blockchain, script, p2sh

What is the limit in bits for the plain-text data of a secret (the data that it is actually hashed and used in a script) in a hash locked contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [maximum number of bytes pushable to the stack is set to 520 bytes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/10b22e3141a603ec891d2cfc7100c29c7409aabe/src/script/script.h#L22), so that would be the maximum plain-text data of a secret (if you want to be able to redeem the output afterwards).

Another question discussing about this limit can be found [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38937/what-was-the-original-rationale-for-limiting-the-maximum-push-size).